# Which keybind for smart-searching in history with ZSH?

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion

When using the up and down arrow in my terminal (`iTerm 2` on `Mac OS Catalina`), I can browse through my last commands using the up and down arrows.

I use `ZSH` (`Oh-my-zsh` to be precise) and if I type e.g. `vim` then press up, it will browse my history for any commands issued starting with `vim`.

I think it's annoying to have to move my hand to the arrow keys, so i wanted to bind `ctrl-j` and `ctrl-k` for browsing up and down.

I looked at `bindkey` and bound `^j` to `down-history` and `^k` to `up-history`. This allows me to  browse my history, but not with the "smart" functionality (i'm not sure of the right terminology here) - It simply goes up and down in my history, without regards to my input.

I've looked through [the standard widgets](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Standard-Widgets) on the `Zsh Line Editor` manual, but I cannot find the right command for this.

Which command should I bind `^j` and `^k` to to get my desired result?

Comment: Check the output of `bindkey | grep -F '^[[A'`; that should show you the widget that up-arrow is currently bound to.

Comment: That was actually a great suggestion. It gave me back `up-line-or-history`, so naturally I bound `^p` to that. Unfortunatly i still only get what seems to be `up-history` without the "smart" search.

Answer (score 5):

After some further digging, i ended up on the [The Z-Shell Line Editor](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide04.html) page at the section called "Prefix searching".

It revealed that the widget I was after, is called `history-beginning-search-backward`.
When using that widget, it works almost as I wanted it to, but not jumping to the end of the line.

A quick search lead me to another [StackOverflow Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/347393/moving-cursor-to-end-of-line-when-using-history-search-backward), that states that if you want to jump to the end of the line (as with the up arrow), it should be done as follows;

> I had the same question and managed to find the solution with some experimentation.
>
> I added the following to my .inputrc

```
"\eOA": history-search-backward # Up

"\eOB": history-search-forward  # Down

"\C-P": "\eOA\C-E"              # Ctrl-P

"\C-N": "\eOB\C-E"              # Ctrl-N
```

> This binds two hotkeys to Ctrl-P and Ctrl-N. One for history search, and the other Ctrl-E for end-of-line.

Comment: Nice. Been searching for an hour on this. Thanks!

Comment: I get a command not found: \eOA: